# mod_rewrite: Convert query strings to hyphenated page links

Tags: string, mod-rewrite, hyperlink

How do I convert this URL to something that looks like a page:

http://www.example.com/search-results/?action=search&type%5Bequal%5D=Blog&keywords%5Bany_words%5D=visual+basic

I want to convert the above URL to:

http://www.example.com/blogs/visual-basic

When the user clicks on the converted short link 2, it should go to the long URL 1 listed on the top.

I tried this but it does not work:

```
RewriteRule ^blogs/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\.html$ /search-results/?action=search&type%5Bequal%5D=Blog&keywords%5Bany_words%5D=$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you question is wrong or your RewriteRule is wrong.

You want the user to type `http://www.example.com/blogs/visual-basic`

and this address to be internally rewritten to:

```
http://www.example.com/search-results/?action=search&type%5Bequal%5D=Blog&keywords%5Bany_words%5D=visual+basic
```

There's no "html" ending the URL in your user address. Thus, try this, it should work:

RewriteRule ^blogs/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /search-results/?action=search&type%5Bequal%5D=Blog&keywords%5Bany_words%5D=$1 [NC,L]